# How do I get the IP address of a locally connected device by its hostname in Dart/Flutter?

Tags: python, flutter, networking, dart

I am working on an app in Flutter and can't figure out how to get the IP address of a locally connected device by its hostname.
In Python I would do something like this:

```
hostname = socket.gethostbyname(socket.getfqdn('HOSTNAME'))
```

How would I do this in Dart/Flutter?

Comment: have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [ipfinder](https://pub.dev/packages/ipfinder) library.

```
import 'package:ipfinder/ipfinder.dart';

void main() async {
  Ipfinder ipfinder = Ipfinder("YOUR_TOKEN_GOES_HERE");
  IpResponse ip = await ipfinder.getAddressInfo("1.0.0.0");
  print(ip.toJson()); // print json data
}
```

Comment: How we get this Token ?